# What labor is used to Pit/Pond Large Animals?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

What labor is used to throw animals in pits? I decided to throw all of my non-thief goblin prisoners down my execution shaft, but a human caravan outside keeps attacking them all even though they've been done trading for months, and it's getting bothersome. I didn't want to cancel their assignment to the pit and then re-assign them all since that would take a while, so I would like to just cancel the relevant labor in all of my dwarves so they'll stop moving them so the humans will leave. Which labor is needed for that?

I've canceled Animal Hauling, but the wiki only mentions that being used for animal-filled cages. They're still being moved, but that might just be because it takes a while for them to finish their current task. I also thought that it might be Animal Training or Animal Care, but the wiki only mentions those as being used for actual animal training and nothing, respectively. Which labor is it that I need to cancel?

Comment: i know animal care is bugged and has no real use currently, so says the wiki.

Comment: Hm, that's a very good question. I wish I could do some testing and find out, but I just threw all my captives into a room with my military stationed in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pen/Pasture and Pit jobs have no assigned labor currently. Any dwarf can and will do it, and you can't control which.

Presumably a future update will make it use Animal Hauling.

Comment: Animal hauling has been implemented as a separate labor as of version 2014 (40d) of dwarf fortress. It was probably implemented in some earlier version such as v0.34.

Answer (score 0):

The labor Animal Hauling is used to move animals between cages, and to catch loose animals and put them in the appropriate pen/pasture.

Presumably, taking an animal to a pit would use Animal Hauling or garbage dumping, depending on how Toady reasoned when he coded it.